# How to print the values that were not found in any line?

Tags: python

```
def matchTest(testsuite, testList):
  suite=open(testsuite, 'r')
  line1=suite.readlines()
  for line in line1:
    for test in testList:
      if re.search(test, line, re.IGNORECASE):
        for i in line.split(","):
          if "component=>" in i:
            search_word = re.search("\"(.*)\"", i).group(1)
            testcase=test
            name.append(testcase + "," + search_word)
```

In the code snippet :

`testsuite` is a list of files.
`testList` is the list of testcases.
I will search for each testcase in the list of testcases, in each file in the list of files. If the testcase is found in any line of any file, I will search for the component name in that line and extract the component value if it exists (which it may, or may not).

**Problem:**

Now, if the testcase is not found in line of any files, then I should print those.
Currently, when I try to print the testcases which were not found in any of the files, it is printing all the testcases many times in the list

The line in each file looks like following with different values:

```
{ :component=>"Cloud Tier Mgmt", :script=>"a.py", :testname=>"local_metadata_consumption_two_cp", :params=>"--ddrs=$DDRS --clients=$LOAD_CLIENT --log_level=DEBUG ", :numddr=>1, :timeout=>10000 }
```

Testcase in list (testList) looks like following:

```
local_metadata_consumption_two_cp
testname1
testname2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One performance issue is that you are using `.split()` on each line, iterating over a tag, then using regex to extract a string. If you want to find e.g. the testcase name, you just need, e.g.:

```
test_case = re.search(r":testname=>\"([^\"]*)", line).group(1)
```

to extract the test case name from a line.

```py
import re

def matchTest(testsuite, testList):
    names = []
    tests_found = set()
    test_set = set(testList)

    for file in testsuite:  # Loop over each file in turn
        line1 = open(file, 'r').readlines()
        for line in line1:
            # extract test case from line
            test_case = re.search(r":testname=>\"([^\"]*)", line).group(1) 
            if test_case in test_set:
                # If test case is in the testList, write test name + component name to names
                search_word = re.search(r":component=>\"([^\"]*)", line)
                # Allowing for situation when 'component=>' does not exist in file to avoid AttributeError:
                if search_word:
                    search_word = search_word.group(1)
                else:
                    search_word = "None"

                names.append(test_case + "," + search_word)
                # Add test to set of tests_found
                tests_found.add(test_case)


    print("TestList tests found in file:\n{}".format("\n".join(names)))
    print("\nTestList tests not in file: {}".format(test_set.difference(tests_found)))

test_list = ["local_metadata_consumption_two_cp", "testname1", "testname2"]
file_list = ["test.txt", "test2.txt"]
matchTest(file_list, test_list)
```

So, this now reads all of the files, one by one, and for each file, if a record contains a test that is listed in `testList` it appends the name of the test and the name of the component from the same line to `names`, and adds the name of the test to a set of test_cases found.

There is no need to try to track tests not found (which is not possible on a line-by-line basis) but as we know which tests have been found, and the total list of possible tests, we can just use set operations to identify which tests have been found that are in `testList`, and which tests did not appear in any file.

If you want to eliminate exact duplicates (i.e. `testname` and `component` were identical on the same line) you can change the print statement to:

```
    print("TestList tests found in file:\n{}".format("\n".join(set(names))))
```

On my short test with two files with two records in each file, my output was:

```
TestList tests found in file:
local_metadata_consumption_two_cp,Cloud Tier Mgmt1
local_metadata_consumption_two_cp,Cloud Tier Mgmt3
testname1,Cloud Tier Mgmt4

TestList tests not in file: {'testname2'}
```